# Honda Civic Mk8 FK3 interfacing with ECU/body computer

Tags: honda, civic, electronic-control-module

I wanted to create a few improvements for a FK3 Civic, such as:
- automatic door locking
- automatic cornering lights

For those, I need to be able to read few parameters from the car's computers:
- current speed
- steering wheel angle
- current gear
- headlights status

I searched quite a bit, but it seems that nobody knows how to interface Civic Mk8 computers (save for OBD-II mandated information, which includes speed, but not steering wheel angle or headlights status).

Is there any information on how to access that available somewhere?

Comment: Automatic door locks could be done with OBD-II data. Just read the engine RPM and the door switch. If RPM = 0 and the door switch = closed then go ahead and lock the doors. This will not lock the doors without the keys in the ignition. What do you mean about automatic cornering lights? Like when you turn the wheel you want the turn signals to turn on by themselves?

Comment: @racefever I *think* OP means corner markers aka parking lights, daytime running lights?

Comment: I see the OP wanting their headlights to turn into a turn when cornering like the system BMW has with their headlights.

Comment: What year is this vehicle.  There is a recall on some model years for the BCM (body control modules)

Comment: @DucatiKiller Cornering lights come on with the turn signals to illuminate the turn but only when the headlight are on as well. My Grandmarquis has them. You would need head light and turn signal status.

Comment: @vini_i  Do many cars have a sensor for steering wheel angle?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Dynamic stability control requires steering wheel angle. Also many if not all direct electric power steering systems need steering angle as well. (I'm reffering to the systems that have no hydraulic components at all because some power steering has an electric pump for the hydraulic fluid)

Comment: @vini_i  good info.TY.

Comment: I wasn't sure what is the name of the function in English - I want a function where one of the front fog lights switch on when navigating a turn, per EU law this is only allowed when going slower than 40 kph. As for the wheel angle, it has to be there- VSA depends on it. About locking- in my previous car it only kicked in when running at 15 mph or so; in Civic I also need unlocking when entire is turned off, for safety reasons and also because the door handle does not open the lock if engaged.